# Cannot change colorscheme in vim

Tags: vim

I'm struggling trying to set a colorscheme in vim. I installed many themes like jellybeans, gruvbox, molokai (from the AUR, I use Manjaro Linux) but writing `colorscheme name_of_the_colorscheme` with any of these in either in my `.vimrc` or in `/etc/vimrc` doesn't work. I get apparently random colors, such as with jellybeans, of the default theme with gruvbox.
Manually setting it with `:colo` from within vim works fine, though.
I noticed that when I run vim from the terminal, it takes two or three seconds to load, and when I quit it leaves an empty line, like

```
davide@drogon ~ $ vim .vimrc

davide@drogon ~ $
```

opposed to

```
davide@drogon ~ $ vim .vimrc
davide@drogon ~ $
```

as it usually does (and should do).

Interesting thing, I do the same exact thing with my laptop, and there it works flawlessly. On my desktop pc, it doesn't. I even copied `.vimrc` and `/etc/vimrc` from the laptop to the desktop but the issue persists.
`$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`, and I even tried writing `set t_Co=256` in the rc files, but even this is useless.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you launching vim by using `vi`? Vim and vi are seperate programs.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't mention it, I set an alias in my `.bashrc` that substitutes `vi` with `vim`. The issue isn't related to that, though, using `vim` doesn't solve this. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

As you'r not sure about where the last `colorscheme` command is executed, also the end-result is apparently random. Debugging the `vim` start-up is a easy way to go:

```
vim --cmd 'profile start profile.log' \
    --cmd 'profile func *' \
    --cmd 'profile file *' \
    -c 'profdel func *' \
    -c 'profdel file *' \
    -c 'qa!' && grep --color -in "colorscheme" profile.log
```

this will print all the `colorscheme` options executed while starting vim. You can work-up from there.

Comment: Okay, I disabled the line in `.vimrc` that prevents shell from keeping vim colorschemes when quitting, and now colors aren't random, but it keeps loading only the default colorscheme. I also removed the colorscheme line from `/etc/vimrc`. I don't know what to do with that output, though... I can't find anything useful.